# Display Vertical bar chart with grouped bars.

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I am trying to create barchart using google charts. I want to display both Sales Orders and Sales Quotations total value each month. Now i have done it like this, it displays only orders value for each month that too in horizontal format. I am not getting how to show both the values using single barchart (vertically)

here is my code

```
$query = "SELECT MONTHNAME(last_modified) as month, 
                 orders.sales_order_id, 
                 orders.authorise, orders.company_id,
                 before_order_line_items.sales_order_id,
                 before_order_line_items.item,
                 before_order_line_items.uom, 
                 SUM(before_order_line_items.total) AS 'Total',
                 before_order_line_items.tax from orders INNER JOIN  
                 before_order_line_items ON
                 orders.sales_order_id ON    
                 before_order_line_items.sales_order_id  
           where orders.order_quote = 'Order' 
           AND orders.authorise='Yes' 
           GROUP BY MONTH(orders.last_modified) 
           ORDER BY MONTH(orders.last_modified)";

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $myurl[] = "['".$row['month']."', ".$row['Total']."]";

    }

<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Actuals'],
         /* ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]*/


            <?php echo implode(",", $myurl); 

            ?>

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Orders',
          vAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: change [`BarChart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) to [`ColumnChart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) for vertical bars -- as for _both the values_, looks like you need help with the sql, correct?

Comment: yes, in both sql and in display

Comment: i can try to help, but have more questions first. does the above sql give correct results for orders? would _Quotations_ be found with -- `where orders.order_quote = 'Quote' `? do you plan to use only month and total?

Comment: Yes. where `orders.order_quote = 'Quote'/'Order'`, Yes, Its only month and total value

Comment: can i see your database structure? pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, need to adjust sql to return *both the values*

then add columns to `$myurl[]`

`$myurl[] = "['".$row['Month']."', ".$row['Quotes'].", ".$row['Orders']."]";`

from there, draw the chart, but recommend using `loader.js` vs. older library `jsapi`

something like this should be close...

```
$query = "SELECT
            MONTHNAME(last_modified) as Month,
            SUM(case when orders.order_quote = 'Order' then before_order_line_items.total else 0 end) AS Orders,
            SUM(case when orders.order_quote = 'Quote' then before_order_line_items.total else 0 end) AS Quotes
          FROM orders
          INNER JOIN before_order_line_items
          ON orders.sales_order_id = before_order_line_items.sales_order_id
          WHERE orders.authorise = 'Yes'
          GROUP BY MONTH(orders.last_modified)
          ORDER BY MONTH(orders.last_modified)";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $myurl[] = "['".$row['Month']."', ".$row['Quotes'].", ".$row['Orders']."]";
}

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawChart,
    packages: ['corechart']
  });

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Quotes', 'Orders'],
      <?php
        echo implode(",", $myurl);
      ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Orders',
      vAxis: {
        title: '',
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `SELECT MONTHNAME(last_modified) as Month, SUM(case when orders.order_quote = 'Order' then before_order_line_items.total else 0 end) AS Orders, SUM(case when orders.order_quote = 'Quote' then before_order_line_items.total else 0 end) AS Quotes FROM orders INNER JOIN before_order_line_items ON orders.sales_order_id=before_order_line_items.sales_order_id WHERE orders.authorise = 'Yes' GROUP BY MONTH(orders.last_modified) ORDER BY MONTH(orders.last_modified)` Edited your query as there is a small syntax error

Comment: But its giving the proper result.

Comment: Nothing is getting displayed, But this error (mozilla firebug) `
Error: Invalid row type for row 1, loader.js, line 138`

Comment: don't need comma at end because of `implode` -- sorry, missed that. see edit above...

Comment: Yes. Its giving result as i wanted. Thanks. if i want to do it from month March to April, how can it be?

Comment: does it show more than March to April now? if so, add to sql where clause -- `and last_modified between '2016-03-01' and '2016-04-30'`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much

Comment: cheers! actually, may want to use -- `between '2016-03-01' and '2016-05-01'` -- or add the time -- `between '2016-03-01' and '2016-04-30 23:59:59'` -- not sure if above would include datetime value of `2016-04-30 01:30:00` for instance -- assuming `last_modified` includes time values